# How to make a click- and see-through 'always on top'-window

Tags: c#, delphi, always-on-top

I want to display an semi-transparent always-on-top window with some information, but I do not want this window to take input or receive focus. All mouse-clicks should go to the underlaying window.

I remember seeing this in a shell-replacement application years back, but I can't remeber witch.

Any Ideas how to achieve this effect with delphi or c#?

Update:

I can't quite get the proposed solution to work with delphi. Returning HTTRANSPARENT for the NCHITTEST-message will stop all mousemessages reaching the form, but it want pass it down to the next window in z-order. Is this method ment to work across processes, or is it only ment to work on childelements of a spesific window?

If I set the ExStyle flag WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, though, all mouseclicks will travel through into the next window, but I will not get the NCHITTEST-message at all, and will not be able to control where the windows should be click-through or not...

Answer (score 5):

[This StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112224/click-through-transparency-for-visual-c-window-forms) should answer your question hopefully.

Comment: Thanks! I shall try this out as soon as possible. I will also try to be better at searching... :-)

Comment: Note: This will only be click-through where the window is transparent. If you have, say, a label or image of some sort, these would not be click through.

Comment: I'm not sure about that actually - have you tested it? If so, you can still get around that issue by intercepting *all* Windows messages for the application and returning that hit test result.