# Is it possible to make JWindow which is transparent and is clickable through?

Tags: java

I have JWindow which is semi transparent so you can see whatever is on desktop. Then I have it set to be always on top. That all works fine but what i would like to do next is to be able to click whatever is behind JWindow. I can see what is behind but there is some default listener or something that changes my mouse and not being able to click through it. If anyone has suggestion on how to achieve that i would be glad to hear it.

```
public Class extends JWindow {
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    setSize(100, 100);      
    setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 0, 10));        
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/28772306/2232127

Comment: I saw that but I was thinking if there is anything to do with java without using JNA